# ios - Individual key vs Storing structured data in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios

I have like 100 levels in my game and I want, for example, to store completion rate (in %) and highscore (int)

What would be the best way to accomplish it with NSUserDefaults?

Should I use individual keys for that like

```
"levelCompletion%number%", "levelHighscore%number%"
```

or maybe store a collection somehow

```
"levelInfo%number%"
```

And an object for levelInfo key would be NSDictionary, for example.

Which way is more efficient?

Comment: The best solution is not to use NSUserDefaults. Put them in a collection and save the collection to the Documents directory, set encryption or explicitly encrypt if security is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a dictionary with all of the keys for each level, and nothing/empty/NSNumber(0) values. That way when the defaults are spooled out, all 100 will be there for examination, although normally most would be "0".

There is no efficiency concern here, this is a triviality in storage terms and should be at the bottom of any list of premature optimization!